# Efficiently Unnest values within Bigquery? (Select/Case/other?)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm currently working with Google analytics data within BigQuery. Currently, I have to unpack a lot of custom dimensions at the hit level. So far, I've come across two methods of doing this:

```
  SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN hitcd.index=1 AND hitcd.value is not null THEN hitcd.value ELSE NULL END) as case_example,
  (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(h.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index =1) as select_example
  FROM 
  `dataset.ga_sessions_20200401` as t,
  UNNEST(customDimensions) as sess_cd,
  UNNEST(t.hits) as h,
  UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hitcd
```

Both of these seem... less than elegant. Ideally, I'm trying to select specific index/values out of the array and return a flattened data structure to be more reporting friendly.

Is there a better more efficient way to accomplish this? The goal is to produce a query to flatten out several million records across the past 2 years.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: no. there is no better way! depends on specific case/goal either first or second way can better serve

Answer (score 0):

First: Be very careful with that!

When you do something like:

```sql
 `dataset.ga_sessions_20200401` as t,
  UNNEST(customDimensions) as sess_cd,
  UNNEST(t.hits) as h,
  UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hitcd
```

You are producing an explosive number of records. Let's say that in one single row customDimensions has 10 elements, t.hits has 20, and h.customDimensions has 5. Then you will be creating 1000 rows out of a single one!

Probably that's not what you want - and data is nested to prevent that.

Before flattening you need to decide: How do you expect flatten data to look?

Comment: Right - this is the sad truth haha. In the actual end goal I need to flatten to hit level data and aggregate from there. 

If you're not familiar with the GA data in BigQuery: all hits (clicks/pagesviewes/etc) are stored within 1 record for a session. These need to be unnested. From there each hit has certain nested variables that I need to be their own column. So a more efficient query might leave off the last  "UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hitcd" part. The other UNNEST statements are still needed as far as I'm aware.

Comment: yeah, please add to the question how you expect the data to look at the end of the operation... otherwise nested is perfect, or go for normalization to other tables and JOIN